# Mathematics in selection of RC time constant for an envelope detector for AM

Tags: capacitor

> Let the capacitor be charged to voltage \$ V(t_0) \$ at \$ t=t_0 \$ and then start discharging. At time \$ t(>t_0 )\$, the delayed capacitor voltage is $$ v(t)=V(t_0)e^{(- \frac{t-t_0}{RC})} \tag 1$$
>
> The rate of change of \$ v(t) \$ AT \$ t=t_0 \$ is
>   $$\frac{dv}{d(t-t_0)}|_{t=t_0}=-\frac{V(t_0)}{RC} \tag 2$$

My doubts:

1. When they are saying rate of change of \$v(t)\$ , why have they
   differentiated \$ v(t) \$ with respect to \$ (t-t_0)\$, why haven't they differentiated with respect to \$t\$ and then subtituted \$ t \$ with \$ t_0 \$ , which gives the same answer as shown: $$\frac{dv}{dt}=V(t_0)e^{\frac{t_0}{R_C}}\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-\frac{t}{RC}})$$

   $$=V(t_0)e^{\frac{t_0}{RC}}e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}(-\frac{1}{RC})$$

   $$=>\frac{dv}{dt}|_{t=t_0}=-\frac{V(t_0)}{RC} $$
2. How to differentiate \$ v(t)\$ w.r.t \$ (t-t_0)\$. I am particularly confused about this because of the component \$ V(t_0) \$ of eq \$ (1) \$. Should I consider it a constant or should I consider it a variable as I am differentiating \$ v(t) \$ with respect to \$ (t-t_0)\$. In other words how to do this differentiation?

Comment: first time see such equation [2]. Rate of change is simply \$\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$ dt is a very small amount of time, infinitesimal time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about EE but is just about math.

Comment: Can anyone clarify my doubt, if my method of approach as shown in the yellow box is correct or not. I am trying to find the conditions under which, the capacitor voltage decay will be less than or equal to rate of decay of envelope function,in which I am facing issues with finding rate of capacitor voltage  decay.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand here is not the exact words but the meaning which they are trying to convey. Here t0 is used to represent initial time(which is constant), ie starting time and t is anytime in future(which is a varibale). The same equation can be solved in many ways but here it's not the mathematics which is important but the idea he is trying to convey hence the approach.

For solving this you can take differentiation by substitution approach, ie put t-t0=p and then solve the equation and you will still get the same answer. The idea is don't get confused by t-t0, just treat them as a single variable.

PS:- This question is off topic, you can ask such question on [mathematics platform.](https://math.stackexchange.com/)